# Need to find analytical solution to limit of $\left(1-z\left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)\right)^{n}$ as n approaches infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

When graphing the function

$\left(1-z\left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)\right)^{n}$

as a function of N, you can show that as N approaches infinity, the expression converges to $\frac{1}{a^{z}}$. If its possible, I'd like to know the analytical proof. I've tried binomial expansion but could't find a way to the solution, but my infinite sum/series knowledge may just be too limited. Any help?

In this expression, a and z are real scalars, for the problem I'm solving $a>1$ and $0<z<1$ if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=\left(1-z\left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)\right)^{n}$$
$$\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{\log (a)}{n}-\frac{\log ^2(a)}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Truncated
$$\log(y)=n\log\Bigg[1-z \left(\frac{\log (a)}{n}-\frac{\log ^2(a)}{2 n^2}\right)\Bigg]$$
$$\log(y)=n\Bigg[-\frac{z \log (a)}{n}-\frac{(z-1) z \log ^2(a)}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\Bigg]$$ that is to say
$$\log(y)=-z \log (a)-\frac{(z-1) z \log ^2(a)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Using $y=e^{\log(y)}$
$$y=a^{-z} \Bigg[1 +\frac{(1-z) z \log ^2(a)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\Bigg]$$

Comment: Where does the series with logarithms come from in the second line? Is that a taylor expansion?

Comment: @user5678. Yes, it is Taylor $$\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}=1-a^{-\frac1 n}=e^{-\frac {\log(a)} n}$$

Comment: @user5678. Sorry for a typo. $$\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}=1-a^{-\frac1 n}=1-e^{-\frac {\log(a)} n}$$